# Adding z-index to php while loop

Tags: php, css

I have a procedural while loop that echos out rows in my DB like:

```
echo '<tr align="left"> <td>'.$row['address'].','.$row['state'].'</td>'.
        '<td><a href="'.$row['shopurl'].'">'.$row['datedesc'].'</td>'.
    '</tr>';
```

And works great! The problem now is that I need to add a "SOLD OUT" **png** across the address & state, of only one (currently) of the rows.  I have CSS:

```
#sold-out{
    background-image: url("/graphics/png/soldout.png");
}
```

With the image as the back-ground.

How can I add a Z-Index to php inside a While loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want the image to be at the top of your content? And what do you want to add z-index to?

Comment: there's no `z-index` in php, you would want to have a `if/else` in your loop to determine if it is sold or not and then you can add a `id="sold-out"` accordingly

Comment: What do want to say with "currently"?

Comment: I need the png to ride up and display over the $row['address'] with opacity of .8

Comment: @RodneySalcedo This is an events table and  the" currently" means that other events could be sold out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not add z-index to PHP, you add it to CSS. However, in this case, you can simply print out an absolutely positioned div with the image in the `td` that you want.

PHP

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr align="left">
            <td>';

            //conditional to determine if row is sold out
            if ($row['soldOut'] === 'yes') {
                echo '<div class="sold-out">&nbsp;</div>';
            }

    echo $row['address'].','.$row['state'].'</td>'.
           '<td><a href="'.$row['shopurl'].'">'.$row['datedesc'].'</td>'.
         '</tr>';
}
```

CSS

```
.sold-out {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url("/graphics/png/soldout.png");
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
```